# What are your favorite skeleton files for the various languages?

Tags: ide, code-generation

It is useful to have skeleton or template files that you can just copy and use as a basis for a new script or app.

For example, I use the following ones (emacs with the auto-insert module automatically opens a copy of the appropriate skeleton file when I create a new file).

**Perl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 

use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $verbose = 1;

GetOptions("verbose!" => \$verbose
) or die("options error");
```

**C++**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  try{

  }
  catch(std::exception& e){
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Arguably, one could include basic code for `boost::program_options` etc.

What are your favorite skeleton files?

Answer (score 3):

My Perl templates look like this:

If I am opening a .pm module:

```
use MooseX::Declare;
class What::Ever {

};

1;
```

Or, if not on a [MooseX::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Declare) project:

```
package What::Ever;
use Moose;

1;
```

If it's a .pl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.10';
```

Since I use autoinsert.el, I also have it ask me if I want to use FindBin; if so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.10';

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/../lib";
```

The necessary emacs code is in my elisp repository at http://github.com/jrockway/elisp/blob/fd5d73530a117a13ddcde92bc1c22aba1bfde1f0/_local/auto-inserts.el.

Finally, I think you will prefer [MooseX::Getopt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Getopt) to plain Getopt.  It is a much more maintainable approach to writing "one-off" scripts.  (The next few lines go something like:

```
use My::Script;                    # that's why we did the "use lib" thing
My::Script->new_with_options->run; # this parses the command line, creates a new object, and runs the script
```

All the important code goes in a class that can be unit tested, glued to a web app, etc.)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know MooseX. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The only skeleton file I have is for LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cancel}
\oddsidemargin0cm
\topmargin-1cm
\textwidth16.5cm
\textheight23.5cm
\parskip1ex
\parindent0ex
\begin{document}
\title{ ... }
\author{ ... }
\date{ ... }
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Obviously I use this for writing math papers.

Otherwise, I always start from scratch.  There's no programming language I can think of where the requisite infrastructure is more than you can keep around in your brain or take longer than 20 seconds to type out.

Comment: Multiply the number of files you create in your lifetime by the 4 lines of boilerplate per file.... and I think you'll find it worthwhile to let your editor do the typing.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio, they're called Project files; my current favorite is Windows Application ;-)

Comment: still no sense of humor on SO - very sad

Answer (score 1):

**Java**

```
package edu.vt;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class Template
{
   private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

   /* Constructors
   ***************************************************************************/

   public Template()
   {
   }

   /* Accessors/Mutators
   ***************************************************************************/

   /* Local Methods
   ***************************************************************************/
}
```

and

```
package testing.edu.vt;

import edu.vt.Template;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class TemplateTestCase extends TestCase
{
   private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public TemplateTestCase(final String name)
    {
      super(name);
    }

    protected void setUp()
    {
    }

    protected void tearDown()
    {
    }

    public void testLifeCycle() throws Exception
    {
      assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need all those *******... comments, especially considering you can jump to any method definition with a few keystrokes?

Comment: Most code is a candidate for an open source contribution, where it's nice to give context. And I already did everyone a favor and left out the Javadoc comment blocks. Remember, these are skeleton files.

Answer (score 1):

Python is simple, but it still helps if you import things with shortcut names, for example:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pylab as pyb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
```

But just don't do: import skynet.

Answer (score 1):

**Bourne Shell**

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
cat <<EOF
  $0 <cmd>
cmd:
  samplecmd
EOF
}

cmd=${1}
shift

case ${cmd} in
    samplecmd)
        arg1=${arg1:-${1}} # arg list takes precedence over env var
        if [ "x${arg1}" = "x" ] ; then
            usage
        fi
        samplecmd ${arg1}
        ;;
    *)
        usage
        ;;
esac
```

I like to make little helper scripts like this to document commands I type in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm writing code that will be OSS I have a simple boiler plate template that I can key in the license and URL to the license text.  The boiler plate has author details, and other crap hard coded.

For commercial dev I have a boiler plate with company information, and standard copyright notices in it.

I don't keep any standard skeletons because I've found I just cut out the content and added my own anyway.  Most cases are different enough that changing the skeleton to match takes as long as bashing it out by hand.